# How do I make my REST server in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I am trying to make a RESTful service out of a Rails server.  I have looked at tutorials online and apparently I am doing something wrong.  My error is a CORS problem.  I have a User model and controller.  In my user controller I am trying to change the headers to allow any site to be able to pull information from the server.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def options
    if access_allowed?
      set_access_control_headers
      head :ok
    else
      head :forbidden
    end
  end

  private
    def set_access_control_headers
      # headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.env['HTTP_ORIGIN']
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1000'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*,x-requested-with'
    end


    def access_allowed?
      allowed_sites = '*' #you might query the DB or something, this is just an example
      return allowed_sites.include?(request.env['HTTP_ORIGIN'])
      return true
    end
end
```

I have also set up my routes to so when the server is hit it goes to the 'options' action.

```
  resources :users, :only => [:create]
  match '/users', :controller => 'users', :action => 'options', :via => :get
```

I have created an html page on my development machine and I am just opening it from Chrome (I dont know if this is an issue or not.)  When I try to grab the users, I get

```
OPTIONS http://www.*****.com:3000/users 404 (Not Found) jquery.js:3
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.****.com:3000/users. Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong or point me in a direction that can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Your route specifies accepts a `GET` request (`:via => :get`) but it looks like your actual request is an `OPTIONS` request.

Try changing your `match` to:

```
match '/users', :controller => 'users', :action => 'options', :via => :options
```

Also note that the name of your action does not have to be `options`, it could be whatever you want it to be.

For reference, here is what an `OPTIONS` request [should return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol):

> Returns the HTTP methods that the server supports for specified URL. This can be used to check the functionality of a web server by requesting '*' instead of a specific resource.

And here's [an article](http://www.codeodor.com/index.cfm/2011/7/26/Responding-to-the-OPTIONS-HTTP-method-request-in-Rails-Getting-around-the-Same-Origin-Policy/3387) on responding to options requests in Rails.

Comment: I made the change that you specified.  I also changed `Access-Allow-Control-Methods=*`.  I get the same error in chrome, `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://99.44.242.76:3000/users. Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.  My Rails server complains about `No route matches [GET] "/users"`.  This is why I originally had `:via => :get`.  The article you posted is the same one I used to set up what I have going.  What would you recommend now?

Comment: Hmm... I'll have to think about this some more. But the fact that you're getting a no route error means that it's irrelevant what you put in the controller: the request is never making it that far. This is a routing/request problem.

Comment: I would say take off the `resources` line in your `routes.rb` and also remove the `:via` option from the `match` line, and see if that works first. (That will accept all requests to `/users` regardless off the HTTP action.)

Comment: But the fact that you're making a `GET` request is weird to me, since the whole point seems to be to make an `OPTIONS` request, no? That's a problem outside of rails, so I don't know how to help there.

Comment: If I leave the code alone and use the Postman plugin in chrome, it allows me to make a ajax OPTIONS call to my server.  I then hit my controller and all the methods in it.  I get a status 200 returned, but I still dont get back any JSON. The `No route matching` issue goes away obviously.  I am using Backbone `fetch` to make the call.  How do I use fetch to make an OPTIONS call?  Also, how do I return JSON from an OPTIONS call and not a GET call?

Comment: If you want to respond with different objects depending on the type of call (OPTIONS/GET), then you should define them as separate controller actions and in your `routes.rb` handle them separately, by specifying `:via => :get` and `:via => :options`.

Comment: Also, you don't get any json because you're not returning one. `head` only responds with headers, according to the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses) (I've never actually used it myself). I would suggest looking into [`respond_with`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with), which is a cleaner way to respond to various different types of requests.